# launch N distinct CMDs with commands passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

i am trying to launch an unknown number of subprocesses using python

```
for w in range(len(TrainingList)):
    subprocess.Popen(TrainingList[w],shell=True)
```

where Traininglist is a list with each element being a command string that i want to launch in a seperate cmd

what i have in the code snippet launches all of them in the same cmd as my program